# Binary operator ..< cannot be applied to operands 'Int' and 'Int?'

Tags: ios, swift4

I am trying to figure out a small nuance of Swift. If I have a wrapped Int like numberOfViews is, how can I unwrap it and iterate over it in a for loop. Xcode complains that: Binary operator ..< cannot be applied to operands 'Int' and 'Int?', on the for loop line.

```
    let numberOfViews: Int? = dataSource?.numberOfViews(in: self)
    for i in 0..<numberOfViews ?? 0 {

    }
```

Comment: most likely: `for i in 0..<(numberOfViews ?? 0) { ... }`, if you don't want to unwrap it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can assign a default value by applying `??` to `numberOfViews` before using it in for-loop condition, as:

```
let numberOfViews: Int = dataSource?.numberOfViews(in: self) ?? 0
for i in 0..<numberOfViews {

}
```

**Or,**

> Apply brackets, because `< has higher precedence than ??`:

```
for i in 0..<(numberOfViews ?? 0) {

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is that `..<` has higher precedence than `??`, so the `Range` you are attempting to construct is interpreted as `(0..<numberOfViews) ?? 0`, which fails because `numberOfViews` is indeed optional. Use parentheses as follows:

```
for i in 0..<(numberOfViews ?? 0) {

}
```